# C# always call a base method from the base class

Tags: c#, overriding

Lets assume that we have the following classes:

```
class A {
   public virtual int Number { get { return 1; } }

   public int Foo(){
      return Number;
   }
}

class B : A{
   public override int Number { get { return 2; } }
}
```

As expected, if I'll call the Foo method on an instance of the B class I'll get 2. Is it possible to change the Foo method in such a way that it'll always use the base A.Number property (and return 1)? Something like:

```
public int Foo(){
   return A.Number; 
}
```

Comment: Note: this question is not how to call the base method (eg. if it has the same name as the current method), but is rather how to *prevent polymorphic dispatch* of a virtual member.

Comment: You're right. Can I do it?

Comment: "Maybe", although probably not quite as envisioned - as it breaks the concept behind run-time polymorphism (where it is the *actual* object that matters, not the expression type). You could do `class B : A { public new int Number { get { return 2; } }`. In that case, where `b` is an expression *typed as* `B`, `b.Number` would return 2 but `((A)b).Number` (and `b.Foo()`) would return 1 (not 2). Note the implication this has for `A b2 = b; b2...`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to put the "real" functionality in the virtual member and have the non-virtual member expose it in a non-virtual way.  That's...not really going to work.  That said, all you need to do is reverse that concept:

```
class A
{
    public virtual int Number { get { return Foo(); } }

    public int Foo()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The "real" definition is in the non-virtual member, and the virtual member simply calls it.  This ensures that you only write the functionality once, while still exposing it in both a virtual and non-virtual manor.

Comment: This is my current solution. I was just wondering if I can somehow force the Foo method to always call the base property.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "base" for use methods and properties of class A.

```cs
class B : A
    {
        public override int Number { get { return 2; } }

        public new int Foo()
        {
            return base.Number;
        }
    }
```

Comment: In the following example: `A a = new B(); var foo = a.Foo()` `foo` would be `2`, not `1`; it should be `1`.  Additionally this approach relies on every single child type of `A` adding this implementation (and getting it right), which is not a realistic expectation.

Comment: Yes, probably you're right.
I had understood that the request was simply to use the property Number of class A into method Foo of class B :)

Comment: `B` *has* no `Foo` method.  The requirements are to use the `Number` definition from class `A`, from the `Foo` method of class `A`, even if that method is called on an instance that happens to be of type `B`.